# Cannot run Spark 2.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, permissions, java

I am trying to install [Spark IM](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) in my fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, however I am running into all kinds of problems. The steps I have taken so far were:

1. Download the tar.gz file from the website
2. Unpack it into my Desktop
3. `sudo mv Desktop/Spark/ /opt/`

Then I try to run the file as root `sudo sh /opt/Spark/Spark`, but I get the following error:

```
/opt/Spark/Spark: 150: /opt/Spark/Spark: bin/unpack200: not found
Error unpacking jar files. Aborting.
You might need administrative priviledges for this operation.
```

Since I was running the file as root (using admin) I do not understand why it says that "might need" administrative privileges ...

Here is the output of running `ls -Al`:

```
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 2 pedro pedro 4096 Jul  1  2011 bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 pedro pedro 4096 Jul  1  2011 documentation
drwxr-xr-x 2 pedro pedro 4096 Jan 23 14:28 .install4j
drwxr-xr-x 4 pedro pedro 4096 Jul  1  2011 jre
drwxr-xr-x 6 pedro pedro 4096 Jul  1  2011 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 pedro pedro 4096 Jul  1  2011 logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 pedro pedro 4096 Jul  1  2011 plugins
drwxr-xr-x 3 pedro pedro 4096 Jul  1  2011 resources
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pedro pedro 8528 Jul  1  2011 Spark
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pedro pedro 7520 Jul  1  2011 starter
drwxr-xr-x 3 pedro pedro 4096 Jul  1  2011 xtra
```

The file I am trying to run is a "sh" file, so I do not need to do `sudo chmod +x Spark` right?

Why is this not running? What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Do you've execute permission on `bin/unpack200`?

Comment: I do not think I have unpack200. How can I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this version is that the program tries to run the file `/bin/unpack200` which does not exist. However, the file `/usr/bin/unpack200` does exist. This is due to the fact that this file is in different places depending on the architecture of the machine used - if it is 32bits, it is in one place, if it is 64bits, it is in the other.

I am having this problem because the file was made to run on a 32bit architecture but I am using a 64bits machine.

Therefore to fix this problem one must install 32bits libraries. To do so just type: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`.

---

Source:

- http://forums.visual-paradigm.com/posts/list/2501.html